# Since arrays decay to pointers, why can't I apply const?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, parameter-passing, constants

Observe the following ways that `const` could be applied to a pointer parameter:

```
void fn1(int * i){
  *i = 0; //accepted
   i = 0; //accepted
}
void fn2(int const* i){
  *i = 0; //compiler error
   i = 0; //accepted
}
void fn3(int *const i){
  *i = 0; //accepted
   i = 0; //compiler error
}
void fn4(int const*const i){
  *i = 0; //compiler error
   i = 0; //compiler error
}
```

I will now attempt the same thing with an array syntax.
As you know, arrays decay to pointers when passed as parameters.
Therefore, the behaviour should be the same.
However, **I can't apply const to the decayed pointer whilst using an array syntax.**

```
void fn1(int i[]){
  *i = 0; //accepted
   i = 0; //accepted
}
void fn2(int const i[]){
  *i = 0; //compiler error
   i = 0; //accepted
}
void fn3_attempt1(int i[] const){ //<-- can't apply const this way
  *i = 0; //accepted
   i = 0; //compiler error
}
void fn3_attempt2(int i const[]){ //<-- can't apply const this way
  *i = 0; //accepted
   i = 0; //compiler error
}
...
```

Is there any way to pass an array using array syntax, but avoid re-assigning the pointer?

Comment: Qualifiers must *precede* the variable to be qualified. (thanks Olaf)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: `const` is a _qualifier_ to be precise.

Comment: `int const` is deprecated syntax and an obsolecent feature. qualifiers should preceede the type. It is not clear what you mean. `int i[]` as formal parameter is converted to `int *`

Comment: "As you know, arrays decay to pointers" - I know better. As stated, this is wrong.

Comment: @Olaf links to the depreciation of qualifiers after the type?

Comment: Thanks for asking, I checked again and apparently had wrong memory. It is just deprecated for storage class specifiers, not qualifiers. It is just better practice and more clear to have them before the type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way to specify the constness of the pointer using the array syntax because it makes no sense for actual arrays.

The array syntax for function arguments is somewhat confusing anyway.  It you *really* want to make the function arguments `const`, use the pointer syntax.

If you use one of the extended array syntaxes introduced by C99 for minimum size or multiple dynamic dimensions, I'm afraid there is no solution to specify constness of the pointer.  That's not a real problem IMHO.

Comment: To clarify: you very well can make the array `const`. It is just the converted pointer itself you cannot for the syntax. Not sure if a modern compiler wanrs about modifying the pointer though.